# Prime norm ideals that are also principal

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Landau's prime number theorem gives us an asymptotic formula for counting the number of prime ideals of a number field $K$, with norm at most $X$.

I am interested in the the prime ideals with a prime norm. It is known (thanks to the comments) that prime ideals with prime norms are in fact the majority. But what about these ideals being principal? What faction of these do we expect to be principal?

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_prime_ideal_theorem:  "... so that the prime ideal theorem is dominated by the ideals of norm a prime number." Therefore I guess the quantity you are looking for is still $X/\log(X)$.

Comment: The prime ideals whose norm is not a prime number have natural (or Dirichlet) density 0.

Comment: @KCd: And what about these prime ideals being principal? What fraction of these ideals do we expect to be principal?

Comment: That would be $1/h$, where $h$ is the class number.  This comes from class field theory.

Comment: @KCd: Thanks. Can you please refer me to a source with some lemma like that? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @Siitd: Read about the Chebotarev density theorem and the Hilbert class field.  It is deeper than a "lemma".